# MS SQL Trigger for Creation&Modification

Tags: sql, triggers

I have found a trigger example for Creation and Modification of the record but the question is, should I create those two triggers for each table or is there any way to run them on each update and insert regardless of the table name. Of course the names of the fields will be unique for each table for instance "CreationDate", "LastUpdate". Actually first question should have been, is creating a trigger for such a case a correct practice or should I handle it on code behind?

Here is the trigger that I have found on the internet;

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr[TableName]CreateDate ON [TableName]
FOR INSERT 
AS
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].Created=getdate()
FROM [TableName] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [TableName].[UniqueID]= Inserted.[UniqueID]

GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr[TableName]LastModifiedDate ON [TableName]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].LastModified=getdate()
FROM [TableName] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [TableName].[UniqueID]= Inserted.[UniqueID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers can be created on DML (Tables, Views events) or DDL (Create, Alter, Drop etc). You can not create a generic trigger which applies to all tables, you need to specify the table name.

You could create a script which automates the Trigger scripts creation for all tables if need be.

More info on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just give your trigger the option to run for INSERT AND UPDATE

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_TableName] ON [dbo].[TableName] FOR INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE AS

BEGIN

    /*
     Do stuff here.
    */
    Select * from Inserted

    Select * from deleted
END
```

Comment: You could also set the datatype for Created to a Timestamp and that will automatically set it when the record is created.

As for LastModified, I would set it with code rather than a trigger.  I try and stay away from triggers as much as possible.

Comment: I guess, I couldn't express my question well. Creating just one trigger for both INSERT and UPDATE is great thanks but my main concern, is it possible to create just one trigger to be triggered on each INSERT UPDATE regardless of the table name. In your example I should give a specific table name, I just want to change [dbo].[tr_TableName] with something in place of every table

Comment: This is an excellent design question.  You would need to deploy a trigger for each table if you elect to use a trigger.  Alternatively, you can get around this consideration by changing the datatype of Created and handling LastModified in your code-behind.

Comment: Timestamp is NOT a datetime field.

Comment: Well I typically have the following columns in my tables: CreatedTime, Createdby, Updatedtime and UpdateBy.  I use datetime for the CreatedTime and UpdatedTime fields, which I populate in my code.